# How to rename fields of an annotated query?

Tags: django, orm

I have the following query

```
a = Mainfee.objects.values('collected_by__username').
                       distinct().annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

The result looks like this

```
[{'collected_by__username': u'maindesk', 'amount__sum': 800}]
```

How can I rename the first key to `a` and second key to `b`?

I tried the following

```
m = Mainfee.objects.extra(select = 
   {'a':'collected_by__username'}).values('a').distinct().
    annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

and received this

```
DatabaseError: no such column: collected_by__username
```

I also tried

```
m = Mainfee.objects.extra(select = 
   {'a':'collected_by__username'}).values('collected_by__username').distinct().
    annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

and got

```
[{'collected_by__username': u'maindesk', 'amount__sum': 800}]
```

PS: I want to rename the second field too

Comment: For `values`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598940/how-to-rename-items-in-values-in-django

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the dictionary key of the annotated value by using keyword arguments:

```
m = Mainfee.objects.values('collected_by__username').annotate(b=Sum('amount'))

[{'collected_by__username': u'maindesk', 'b': 800}]
```

There is no quick and easy way to rename a related field, though. You can convert it in Python, but you'll have to ask yourself if that is really necessary:

```
m = Mainfee.objects.values('collected_by__username').annotate(b=Sum('amount'))
m = [{'a': x['collected_by__username'], 'b': x['b']} for x in m]
```

Or maybe this is slightly faster:

```
m = Mainfee.objects.values_list('collected_by__username').annotate(Sum('amount'))
m = [{'a': x[0], 'b': x[1]} for x in m]
```

Both methods will of course force evaluation of the whole queryset and don't allow further filtering/ordering etc. through the queryset's methods.

Also note that the call to `distinct()` is redundant when you're using `values()` or `values_list()` together with `annotate()`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use an [`F()` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) on `collected_by__username`:

> An `F()` object represents the value of a model field or annotated
> column. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and
> perform database operations using them without actually having to pull
> them out of the database into Python memory... `F()` can be used to create dynamic fields on your models...

If you do this inside an `annotate` clause, we can 'rename' the field to `a`. You don't need to use an `F()` expression when calculating the total. See below:

```
from django.db.models import F
    
(Mainfee.objects.values('collected_by__username')
    .annotate(a=F('collected_by__username'), b=Sum('amount'))
    .values('a', 'b'))
```

Making some assumptions about your model, this would produce something like:

```
<QuerySet [{'a': 'item1', 'b': 1234}, {'a': 'item2', 'b': 4321}]>
```

Comment: Could you add some details why this is an answer to the question?

Comment: Added some explanation of `F()` expressions to your answer. Also, whilst you were on the right lines, you hadn't cast the the total to `b`, so I have corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to rename the first key, it seems there is a solution here: [How to rename items in values() in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598940/django-rename-items-in-values) but it returns error in your case since the generated SQL would be:

```
SELECT collected_by__username AS a WHERE ...
```

And of course `collected_by__username` doesn't exist.

Note: this feature is requested here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16735

The 2nd key can be renamed by using: `annotate(b=Sum('amount')`

So try this first:

```
m = (Mainfee.objects
     .extra(select={'a': 'collected_by.username'})  # check your DB for the exact table and field name
     .values('a')
     .distinct()
     .annotate(b=Sum('amount')))
```

I guess it would spit out an exception but it worths a try. Otherwise don't try to rename the first key for now since it would be very hacky anway.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There's no way to do this on a SQL level without a `JOIN` statement, and that would require either hacking into the Django ORM or some raw SQL statements. Even with `Mainfee.objects.raw()` it's not possible, as that requires an id, while you can't select that without grouping by it.

Comment: Yeah that's why I recommend him to drop this idea.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone stumbles on this page.

```
m = Mainfee.objects.extra(select = 'a':'collected_by.username'}).values('collected_by__username','a').distinct().annotate(b=Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: `F` appears to be the better way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598940/how-to-rename-items-in-values-in-django