# Aliasing the dict keys in a Django QuerySet.values call

Tags: python, django

```
>>> ppcs.values('price', 'currency__currency_code')
[{'price': Decimal('562.00'), 'currency__currency_code': u'JPY'}]
```

When using [`QuerySet.values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), is there a way to alias the key names to something else?  For example, rather than the output showing the through-relationship `currency__currency_code`, how can I make the dict key called 'currency' like in the following output:

```
>>> keys = ['price', 'currency']
>>> [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in ppcs.values_list('price', 'currency__currency_code')]
[{'currency': u'JPY', 'price': Decimal('562.00')}]
```

The problem with the idea above is that I don't want a list (nor a generator object) at this stage, I want the output to remain a `ValuesQuerySet` as in the first example.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16735

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: rename items in values()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598940/django-rename-items-in-values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment of klasske fully answers this question (thanks) --> https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16735

In short, here is the Django 1.8+ solution:

```
from django.db.models import F
ppcs.annotate(currency=F('currency__currency_code')).values('price', 'currency')
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible in Django v1.7 or earlier.

I'd have preferred the following syntax as was originally suggested in the ticket, and avoiding the need to import that clunky `F` object, but no dice.

```
ppcs.values('price', currency='currency__currency_code')
```