# How to create left join with group by django model query

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I declared django model as below, I just want to run simple left join with group by query.

### Mysql query

```
SELECT  u.name, COUNT('j.*') as num_jobs FROM `User` as u 
LEFT JOIN Job as j ON u.id = j.userId_id GROUP BY j.userId_id
```

The above query is getting job count of each user.

### Django Model

```
from django.db import models


class Users(models.Model):       
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60,verbose_name="Name",null=True, blank=True)
    email_id = models.CharField(max_length=60,verbose_name="Email Id",null=True, blank=True)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Phone Number")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"
        verbose_name = "Users"
        db_table = "User"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return  str(self.phonenumber) + ": "+ str(self.name)  

class Job(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128,verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description",null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Job"
        verbose_name = "Job"
        db_table = "Job"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.title
```

Do I need to adjust anything in model, please guide me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Count

# import your model (Job)

Job.objects.values('userId').annotate(c=Count('userId')).values('userId__name','c')
```

The initial `values('userId')` followed by `annotate` will count and group by `userId`.

The output will be a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'userId__name':'John','c':20},]
```

Where the user `John` has 20 related `Job` objects.

On an unrelated note, whenever you have foreign keys in your models. It is usually better to write `user` instead of `userId`.

It makes more sense when you write queries and access relations (`user__name` instead of `userId__name`).

**UPDATE:**

If you need other properties, add them as arguments to the second `values` call like this:

```
Job.objects.values('userId').annotate(c=Count('userId'))\
.values('userId__name','userId__email_id','c')
```

Comment: Thanks for excellent solution, can you help how can I get all the columns from user table instead only name column

Comment: I have updated my post to answer your other question.

Comment: Not that I know of, you have to explicitly specify all the properties you need.

Comment: The answer was very helpful, just extending question is it possible to do a coulmn alise **userId__name** is looks weired I want to make **name** since I am exposing it in api. so can django allow us to do something like **userId__name as name**

Comment: There is a way to alias but unfortunately it doesn't go through relations as described in the comments here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10599077/1268926). You can write your own function that renames all keys.  `api_return = [{'name':k['userId__name']} for k in v]` where v is the last query in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the most straight-forward solution would be to get your User objects by:

```
users = User.objects.filter(<filtering-expression-here>)
```

Once you've got the users, you can consider the number of jobs he has by:

```
for user in users:
    print "User '%s' has %s jobs" % (user.name, str(user.job_set.count()))
```

PS: This suggestion assumes that you rename your 'Users' model to 'User' (without the s)

EDIT: I changed len(...) to .count()

Comment: `len` will not work on `user.job_set`. You need to do `user.job_set.count()` or  `len(user.job_set.all())`. Even then, this method is inefficient as you get all properties of the User object (with a filter) and then all related jobs with `user.job_set` (when you just need the count).

Comment: True, thanks for pointing this out the counting stuff.
I agree on your performance remark. However, programatically, this is probably the most easy thing.

Comment: Programatically yes, scalability-wise not so good when you have lots of rows in your db and / or several columns.