# Join two models in Django filter

Tags: python, django

I might be stupid for not finding the right keywords to look for, but here's the actual problem:
I'm trying to *select* database values by joining two different models in `Django`.
Consider the following `models.py`:

```
class Token(models.Model):
    userid = models.TextField()
    access_token = models.TextField()
    refresh_token = models.TextField(default='None', null=True)

class File(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(Token, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField()
    link = models.TextField()
    size = models.BigIntegerField()
```

I'd now like to have all files from `File` with their corresponding `access_token` and `userid`.
I tried to do the following:

```
data = File.objects.filter(name__startswith='Dummystring')
```

How to obtain the access_token in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to join the tables and get the values. Use [`__` to do field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups):

```
data = File.objects.filter(name__startswith='Dummystring') \
                   .values_list('userid__access_token', 'userid__userid')
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks (+1). I wasn't aware that you can do field lookups in the `values()` function as well. Will accept your answer shortly and love `Django` (was more of a `PHP` guy).

Comment: Short follow-up: Now the output looks something like `"userid__access_token": 'test1234'`, can I get rid of the `userid__` prefix?

Comment: That would be this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598940/django-rename-items-in-values. You could just use `values_list` if you only want one or two values, right? It would give you a list of tuples basically.

Comment: Thanks again, will look into it!

Comment: @ShangWang what if no row is found for userid__userid? Is there a possible to return null value?