# Rename nested annotated field via Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm, django-annotate

Is it possible to renaming nested fields using for group by clause?

This query:

```
paymentitem.objects.filter(payment=p).values('item__vat_tax').annotate(base=models.Sum('price')).order_by('item__vat_tax')
```

returns expected data:

```
<QuerySet [{'base': Decimal('41.322'), 'item__vat_tax': 15}, {'base': Dec
    imal('483.470'), 'item__vat_tax': 21}]>
```

I want to rename field '*item__vat_tax*' as '*vat*'. This query:

```
paymentitem.objects.filter(payment=p).extra(select={'vat': 'item__vat_tax'}).values('item__vat_tax').annotate(base=models.Sum('price')).order_by('vat')
```

return the same result but surprisingly ordered by *vat* too.

If I change the field name inside the value statement, it raise an error.

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/32580991/548562

Comment: Yes, it works with F expression. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use F expression:

```
paymentitem.objects.filter(payment=p).values(vat=F('item__vat_tax')).annotate(base=models.Sum('price')).order_by('vat')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the annotate value name in Django. If we use the Django F expression then easily can solve this.

```
from django.db.models import F 
paymentitem.objects.filter(payment=p).values(vat=F('item__vat_tax')).annotate(base=models.Sum('price')).order_by('vat')
```

Return Expected Data

```
<QuerySet [{'base': Decimal('41.322'), 'vat': 15}, {'base': Decimal('483.470'), 'vat': 21}]>
```