Can Django make this multiple tables query in a single statement?
Let simplify the problem. Say I have two models:

class Man(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()
   # other fields

class Job(models.Model):
   man = models.ForeignKey(Man)
   # other fields


Here, my logic is that, some man may have a job, some may not. Now I want to make a query to select men with the info if the man have a job.
If I write the query in SQL, then something like:
select m.*, j.id from man m left join job j on m.id=j.id where m.some_condition

So that if j.id is null, then the man has no job. From the query, I want to return a list of men like:
[
   {"name": "Tom", "has_job": true},
   {"name": "Jack", "has_job": false},
   ...
]

How to make this query in Django ORM?

I found an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76424111/django-join-through-table-even-if-dont-match

To find only Man instances that have a job:
men_with_jobs = Man.objects.exclude(job_set=None)

.exclude(job_set=None) is essentially just syntactic sugar to say .filter(job_set__isnull=False) (which kind of is an instance of following reverse relationships), where job_set is the implicit name of the reverse relationship from Man back to the Job foreignkey.
This will leave you with a queryset containing only Man instances that have at least one Job instance referencing them.
To list all Man instances and also display whether they have a job or not:
men_with_has_job = Man.objects.annotate(
    has_job=Exists(
        Job.objects.filter(man=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
)

annotate() adds any arbitrary field to the original queryset. Exists returns a boolean for the supplied expression. So we're essentially doing this:

Loop over every Man instance in the queryset
Check if there exists a Job instance that references #1
Add the has_job field to #1 and give it the value of #2


Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't meet my need. I just updated my question. Your answer filters out men who has no job, but I want to get all men info and tag every man if he has a job.

Ah, I guess I read it a little sloppily. Updated answer to account for both scenarios. :-)
